# Wrong length of edges

Tags: arcgis-desktop, openstreetmap, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.3, length

I want to make a network analysis with ArcGIS. I am using openstreetmap-data from the Geofabrik but I have big problem: The length of my edges are not the right one. The length of the edge is for example 0,002295 but it should be 1700m. This is the standard coordinate-system (geographic WGS 84).

I project it into WGS 1984 Web Mercator, WGS 1984 World Mercator and Mercator. Of course I have now the right unit, but it still the wrong. Now the length of my shape ist 2788m instead of 1700m.

Sorry, I am very new to ArcGIS and my English is bad. I hope you understand my problem and maybe you can help me!

I am using ArcGis 10.3.

Comment: How big an area are you trying to create a network for? Web Mercator does not preserve length... only shape of features...

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try making adding a new field with a long int as the data type.
2. Right click on the new field and select Calculate Geometry
3. Choose the option (length in meters)
4. select a segment and use the measure tool to make sure it is the same length as it shows in the attribute table.

Comment: What coordinate system does this use? How big of an area does is this really useful for?

Comment: Good point. @DPSSpatial.  My answer was in hopes of finding errors in his tables that he may not have generated himself as a process of elimination.  In his question before it was editied, it seemed as though he was confident in his projection.

Answer (score -2):

I just use the wrong coordinate system. The right is UTM 32N!